# How can I assign keyword varargs in a Python constructor?

Tags: python-2.7, variadic-functions

I call a constructor with arguments s = 1, t = 2, y = 3, but without p. Because p is not defined, it is not set. I have considered using `*` instead of `**`, but I would still like to use keywords.

```
class Creator(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if len(kwargs) > 1:
            self.scenario = kwargs.pop('s')
            self.t = kwargs.pop('t')
            self.y = kwargs.pop('y')
            self.p = kwargs.pop('p')
```

How can I parse the parameters I have selected (i.e. var(kw)args), while ignoring assignment of those that I have not passed?

Comment: _Because p is not defined, it is not set_ On contrary, it **is** set to `None`. Also, `scenario` local variable clearly breaks a pattern and without clear pattern you cannot write generic code for reassigning kwargs to instance variables. Can you precise what you mean by _parsing all parameters_?

Comment: I receive a `KeyError: ` when trying to assign p

Comment: @Rogalski Edited in response to comment

Comment: Ugh, i misread `pop` as `get`. Simply try `kwargs.get('p')` - it returns `None` if key is absent in dictionary.

Comment: @Rogalski Please provide the answer for my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since kwargs is nothing more than dict, all of dict methods may be used on it.

Especially, if you want to retrive potentially-absent value from it, you may use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If
>   default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never
>   raises a KeyError.

So code will look as following:

```
self.p = kwargs.get('p')  # self.p will be None if "p" is not in kwargs
self.p = kwargs.get('p', MY_VALUE)  # self.p will be MY_VALUE if "p" is not in kwargs
```

Alternatively, standard check for membership will do fine:

```
if 'p' not in kwargs:
    pass  # do something
```